# displaying the same content with loginview

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net webpage that has user login enabled.  Inside of my loginview controller I have my anonymous and loggedin code.  Is it possible to have the same code in both, but for example just add a button in the loggedin view.  All I want to do is when the user logs in display the same information except if logged in show a button, that is not shown when user is anonymous.  Any help would be appreciated thank you.  I already tried putting the same code into both anonymous and logged in but I get an error saying that a box already contains a definition for that name.

Comment: Please show your code...

Answer (score 0):

You can try reusing templates in code, as you can create your own template instance, but it really isn't worth the effort.  It would be best to just copy the markup and change the ID's.  I know it's a pain...

You get the naming conflict because it defines the template instance as a single instance, and each instance gets implemented in the control tree (even though it may not be rendered).